# SQLITE, Group by range of 1000s

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database of two columns in sqlite for android

```
  id (INT)     | owner (VARCHAR) 
 1477            jack
 1578            jill
 :               :
 9277            hill
```

1) 
i like to get a count of the following: -
(group by the 1000s range)

```
RANGE    | COUNT
0-999      0
1000-1999  5
:
8999-9999  7
```

2)
I also like to get a count of the following: -
(group by 100s range)

```
RANGE    | COUNT
X1XX       5
X2XX       6
:
X9XX       7
```

3) and also group by 10s range.

I'm stuck with how to do the group by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable 
GROUP BY ??
```

any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integer division by integers in sqlite3 yields integers:

```
select id/1000 as range_id, count(*) as range_count from mytable group by range_id;
```

To group by 100 ids, simply change `1000` to `100`

sqlite3 has a `printf()` function that might be useful in make a pretty column to describe the range if you need something prettier than the integer division of id by group size.

Comment: it works! Thanks for the pointer. For the 100th location i modified range_id to (id%1000)/100 instead.